# Spring Data JPA: modified entity does an updating in the EhCache without @CachePut

Tags: spring, ehcache, spring-data-jpa, spring-3

I am working with:

- Spring Framework 4.0.5
- Spring Data JPA 1.6.0.RELEASE
- EhCache 2.8.3

I have the following ProductServiceImpl methods:

```
@Override
@Cacheable(value="products", key="#product.id")
public Product save(Product product) {
    return this.productRepository.save(product);
}

@Override
@Cacheable(value="products", key="#id")
public Product findOne(Integer id) {
    return this.productRepository.findOne(id);
}

@Override
@CachePut(value="products", key="#product.id")
public Product update(Product product) {
    return this.productRepository.save(product);
}
```

I have a product with id 2 to be saved in the DB(HSQL) with a stock of 1.
According with the three methods shown above the **Key** must be the same, it **2**
through either `key="#id"` or `key="#product.id"`

Now, I understood that caching works in the following way, *how* a HashMap.

```
HashMap products = new HashMap();
products.put(2, product02);
```

In the **Main** class I have the following (I am using comments to let you understand my logic):

```
logger.info("Inserting product02");
// must save the product02 in the cache too
userExecutionService01.executeSaveProduct(product02); 
…
logger.info("-----------------");

logger.info("Getting product02");
product02 = null;
//Must retrieve the object from the cache, it has been already saved. 
//The Stock must be 1.
product02 = userExecutionService01.executeFindProduct(2);
logger.info("Stock {}:", product02.getStock());

//1 + 100 = 101
product02.setStock(product02.getStock().add(new BigDecimal("100.00")));
//Must update database and the cache with the same product with the new Stock 101.
userExecutionService01.executeUpdateProduct(product02, false);

//Must retrieve the object from the cache, it has been already updated. 
//The Stock must be 101.
logger.info("Getting & Printing product02");
userExecutionService01.executePrintProduct(2);
```

The **executeFindProduct** method has

```
@Override
public Product executeFindProduct(Integer id){
    return this.productService.findOne(id);             
}
```

The **executeUpdateProduct** method has

```
@Override
public void executeUpdateProduct(Product product, boolean throwException){      
    logger.info("+++ executeUpdateProduct - start ");
    logger.info("   Alfa: {}", this.productService.findOne(product.getId()).getStock());
    this.productService.update(product);
    logger.info("   Beta: {}", this.productService.findOne(product.getId()).getStock());
    logger.info("+++ executeUpdateProduct - end ");
}
```

With AOP I am doing a control if the Cache is really working.

```
@Before("execution(* *..ProductService.*(..))")
public void beforeServiceLogging(JoinPoint jointPoint){
    logger.info(">Before {} called", jointPoint.getSignature().getName());
}

@Before("execution(* *..ProductRepository.*(..))")
public void beforeRepositoryLogging(JoinPoint jointPoint){
    logger.info(">>Before {} called", jointPoint.getSignature().getName());
}
```

`>` from service and `>>` from repository

The app has a unexpected behaviour about the Cache

If I use:

```
@Override
@Cacheable(value="products", key="#id")
public Product findOne(Integer id) {
    return this.productRepository.findOne(id);
}
```

The result output shows

```
- Inserting product02
- >Before save called
- >>Before save called  //repository has been called, then: saved in DB and Cache
...
- -----------------
- Getting product02
- >Before findOne called
- Stock 1: //Correct, cache returns the expected value (1)
- +++ executeUpdateProduct - start 
- >Before findOne called
-    Alfa: 101.00 //Wrong, data has not been neither updated in the DB nor @Cacheput has been executed
- >Before update called
- >>Before save called //Repository, just then DB and Cache are being updated
- >Before findOne called
-    Beta: 101.00
- +++ executeUpdateProduct - end 
- Getting & Printing product02
- >Before findOne called
- Product [id=2, ... stock=101.00, …]
```

I am very confused, why "alfa" is showing the object with the stock 101?
**The Db has not been called and of course the @Cacheput has not been executed yet.**

Yes, I know I have this sentence: 
`product02.setStock(product02.getStock().add(new BigDecimal("100.00")));`
But has no sense that line in some way does an update into the cache, for that I use **explicitly** the @CachePut

I only know: the EntityManager should be aware of the update for that product02 and wait until the repository executed the update/save method.

If I use

```
@Override
//@Cacheable(value="products", key="#id")
public Product findOne(Integer id) {
    return this.productRepository.findOne(id);
}
```

All works well about Alfa.

What is happening?

Comment: You are updating an object, that object is the same object that is in your cache. You don't get a copy you get the exact same object. Now if you change the exact same object the changes will be applied. I would suspect that when printing the hashcode of the objects (assuming you haven't implemented them yourself) you will see the same hashcode for all objects.

Comment: Thank you, I am going to add a hashcode() and see what happens. But I am confused yet: "You are updating an object" Yes, I've updated its stock to 101 through a setter but I **didn't call** the CachePut to update the Cache. "that object is the same object that is in your cache" I am confused, for me is **not** the same object, I am assuming the Cache has the old object (stock = 1) yet because I didn't call the CachePut and when I call the findOne method using Cacheable it should return the old object with stock 1

Comment: Therefore once I've called the CachePut the Cache named **products** for the key **2** must update that entry with the new product02 that has the new stock value (101) and therefore the old entry with stock value(1) is overridden. I understand the unique way to access the Cache is through the annotations Cacheable and CachePut and CacheEvict

Comment: There is just a single instance of the object, that instance is updated. There aren't multiple instances of the object. That is what I  meant with the same object. Everything you do is on the exact same single instance of the object so changes are visible immediatly.

Comment: I am confused why when I execute a simple setter and updating the stock to 101 the Cache with id 2 has been updated **automatically** when I never called the CachePut method yet.

Comment: I thought the cache process is how the following (01) product02 = map.get(2); (Cacheable) (02) product02.setStock(101); (my edition) **why it updates automatically the map with the the key 2?** (3) map.put(2, product02); (CachePut)

Comment: As I mentioned there is just 1 instance of the object. The object you are modifying is the same instance that is in the cache! It is about object instances... Object X is in the cache, you retrieve object X and modify it. At least with a simple cache that is the case, with a more elaborate one you might get a copy of the object but then you have 2 instances of the object.

Comment: I just have created the **equals** and **hashcode** methods through the IDE. I have the same result. I remember when I do a research in Google have read about a *key* based on: an id(my case) + hashcode. Thank You.

Comment: You shouldn't have implemented hashCode just printed it out and you should get the same result over and over.

Comment: For this situation **seems** useless the CachePut annotation. After to read again the API and other tutorials, CachePut should be used for insertion/create methods. For this case the update method has no sense, unless the database or a special business within an user case do other changes in the object.

Comment: Instead of `@CachePut` you would better use `@CacheEvict`. That way the next retrieve operation would get a fresh copy out of the database.

Comment: Has sense, I am going to do more experiments.